# How do I determine the password attribute value for the Chef "user" resource?

Tags: passwords, chef-infra

I'm trying to create a user account using Chef 11, and am not sure how to calculate the *password* attribute's value.  I've read the User Resource documentation http://docs.opscode.com/resource_user.html, specifically the section "Password Shadow Hash", and am still unsure what exactly to do.

This user is being created on an Ubuntu system, so do I use the *openssl* example they provided and pass the output of that command as the *password* attribute value?

```
openssl passwd -1 "theplaintextpassword"
```

Each time I run the command, however, the output is different.  It also supports various options (-crypt, -1, -apr1), so which one do I use?

I've been looking at the unix passwd command help, which says it encrypts the value but doesn't indicate which method it uses.  Help for shadow and crypt aren't shedding any light either.

For this example, data bags are overkill, I have a value I want to use for this account, and simply want to specify it using the password attribute.

Here's the user resource section:

```
user 'mytestuser' do
  comment "Test User"
  home "/home/mytestuser"
  shell "/bin/bash"
  supports :manage_home => true

  password "what goes here?"

  action :create
end
```

**Update:**

I've determined that the string you specify for the *password* attribute gets written directly into the user's /etc/shadow entry.  I guess the remaining issue is determining what that file expects the value to be, and how it relates to configuring the user's password.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The key was seeing that the *password* attribute value is written directly to the /etc/shadow file.  It was then a matter of reading the man pages for *shadow* and *crypt* and finally understanding (hopefully) how things fit together.  See *The Gory Details* below, if you're interested in some background.

If you're ok with an MD5 hash of the password, use the *openssl* command to generate the encrypted string.  The version I'm using doesn't appear to support SHA algorithms.  Use *openssl passwd --help* to see which options are available to you.

```
openssl passwd -1 -salt "yoursaltphrase"
Password: <enter the password>
$1$yoursalt$fIque2U6AZ.YRAqOu5Eyo/
```

Now use that string in the recipe's *password* attribute:

```
user 'mytestuser' do
  comment "Test User"
  home "/home/mytestuser"
  shell "/bin/bash"
  supports :manage_home => true

  password '$1$yoursalt$fIque2U6AZ.YRAqOu5Eyo/'

  action :create
end
```

As for me, I ended up creating the test user manually, and then copied its encryption string from /etc/shadow as the *password* attribute value for the recipe.

From /etc/shadow, the second field after *mytestuser:* is the encrypted password.

```
   mytestuser:THIS_IS_THE_FIELD_YOU_WANT:16063:0:99999:7:::
```

See *man shadow* and *man crypt*.

**The Gory Details**

Piecing things together from man pages and various user forums, here's what I've learned.  Note that the term *encrypted* here actually means *hashed*, as I don't believe that passwords can actually be decrypted.

The *passwd* command encrypts the user's plain-text password and writes it to /etc/shadow.

/etc/shadow entries contain the user name and the encrypted password in one of various formats.  The man page for "crypt" describes these formats, see its NOTES section.

The encrypted value has the format:

```
$id$salt$encrypted
```

Think of it as having two parts: a salt and the actual encrypted password.

The salt portion consists of two pieces:

1. An optional id prefix, which identifies the encryption algorithm used and has "$" as a prefix and suffix, e.g. "$id$".
2. The salt value, which can be up to 16 characters and is terminated with a "$", e.g. "saltvalue$".  This value is used to calculate the encrypted password.  It is a random string, and is different every time a password is generated.

The id can be one of the following, indicating the encryption algorithm used:

```
blank = DES  (the default when no $id$ prefix is found)
1     = MD5
2a    = Blowfish
5     = SHA-256
6     = SHA-512
```

The encrypted password length is fixed based on the encryption algorithm:

```
DES      =  8 characters
MD5      = 22 characters
SHA-256  = 43 characters
SHA-512  = 86 characters
Blowfish = ???
```

You can use the *openssl passwd* command to generate various password hashes.
It supports the options:

```
-crypt             DES-based standard Unix password algorithm (default)
-1                 MD5-based password algorithm
-apr1              MD5-based password algorithm, Apache variant
-salt string       use provided salt
```