# Created user resource with Chef, can't authenticate and home not created

Tags: linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe

On a precise64 box.

I tried creating a user with Chef using the following declaration:

```
user "myuser" do
  supports :manage_home => true
  shell "/bin/bash"
  home "/home/myuser"
  comment "Created by Chef"
  password "mypassword"
  system true
  provider Chef::Provider::User::Useradd
  action :create
end
```

This succeeds. I can find my user in `/etc/passwd` but the home directory wasn't created and I can authenticate.

```
$ su - myuser
su: Authentication failure
```

What am I missing?

### Update

Found a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386777/how-do-i-determine-the-password-attribute-value-for-the-chef-user-resource)

Comment: The password attribute does not accept a cleartext string. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386777/how-do-i-determine-the-password-attribute-value-for-the-chef-user-resource

Comment: What makes you think I didn't. I am spending so much time on learning Infrastructure as code that I am a bit sensitive to this kind of comments. Seriously, I'd rather get some help. You didn't even point to the doc (??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
openssl passwd -1 "mypassword"
```

Password `$1$YwUKq1QX$qIVeFlybWqOKJjRLed29j`

```
user "myuser" do  
  supports :manage_home => true  
  shell "/bin/bash"  
  home "/home/myuser"  
  comment "Created by Chef"  
  password $1$YwUKq1QX$qIVeFlybWqOKJjRLed29j.  
  system true  
  provider Chef::Provider::User::Useradd  
  action :create  
end
```

Comment: this worked but now I am still getting :
No directory, logging in with HOME=/  despite the supports :manage_home true

Comment: and trying to be resolved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632091/home-directory-is-not-created-with-adding-user-resource-with-chef/23632156?noredirect=1#23632156

Comment: @joel this is working , user is getting created and check in home directory ,whether a folder created on myuser or no not ..?/

Answer (score 0):

Chef hashes the password. Below bypasses it.

```
passwd=%x( openssl passwd -1 'mypassword' )
passwd.delete!("\n") # removes \n from string

user "myuser" do
  manage_home true
  shell "/bin/bash"
  comment "Created by Chef"
  password passwd
  system true
  provider Chef::Provider::User::Useradd
  action :create
end
```