# home directory is not created with adding user resource with chef

Tags: linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe

On a vagrant box precise64 (ubuntu 12.04)

While creating a user resource with Chef, the home directory is not created:

My recipe:

```
user "myuser" do
  supports :manage_home => true
  shell "/bin/bash"
  home "/home/myuser"
  comment "Created by Chef"
  password "myencryptedpassword"
  system true
  provider Chef::Provider::User::Useradd
  action :create
end
```

When I authenticate:

```
$ su - myuser
Password: 
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
```

### Update - The workaround for precise64 (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit)

```
directory "/home/myuser" do
  owner "myuser"
  group "myuser"
  mode 00755
  action :create
end
```

Comment: I have experienced this issue with Chef on Ubuntu 12.04 (I know for sure) and 13.x something (I believe). So the good news is, you're not crazy. I thought it was intended behavior and just worked around it by [creating the home directory](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_directory.html) first, then specifying the user.

Comment: I don't mind the workaround. I will do that.

Comment: For reference, it worked fine with Vagrant / Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit with just `user myuser do` `supports :manage_home => true` `home "/home/myuser"`. Didn't need the workaround to create directories explicitly.

Comment: It worked for me when I added `manage_home true` as a property.

Comment: I know this is years late, but it looks like they changed the default behavior sometime in Chef 12.14.x here https://github.com/chef/chef/commit/f769d7eba17b3f5aa9e0561126bd9f6801c1bac2#diff-96815653a34461853b36e515b424b39f `opts << "-M" unless managing_home_dir?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While system users usually don't have a home dir, chef will create the home dir even for system users if you specify `home`. I've tried it, and cannot reproduce the issue.

What is going on is a little bit hidden in the documentation. The [chef documentations](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_user.html) says:

> system    |    Use to create a system user. This attribute may be used with useradd as the provider to create a system user which passes the -r flag to useradd.

If have a look at the man page of useradd:

> ```
> -r, --system
>      Create a system account.
>
>    System users will be created with no aging information in /etc/shadow, 
>    and their numeric identifiers are chosen in the SYS_UID_MIN-SYS_UID_MAX
>    range, defined in >/etc/login.defs, instead of UID_MIN-UID_MAX 
>    (and their GID counterparts for the creation of groups).
>
>    Note that useradd will not create a home directory for such an user,
>    regardless of the default setting in /etc/login.defs (CREATE_HOME). 
>    You have to specify the -m options if you want a home directory for
>    a system account to be created.
> ```

However, it seems like chef **is** passing the `-m` option explicitly if you specify a home dir. I could not reproduce this issue therefore.

Comment: I have tried removing the attribute but it didn't resolve. Actually out of desperation I had added it. Thx anyway

Comment: @joelmaranhao On my system (ubuntu 14.04) a home dir for `myuser` get's created. Which system are you using? Are you sure that the user doesn't already existed before the chef run?

Comment: No the user doesn't exist. I am using a vagrant box precise64 (ubuntu 12.04). Updated my questions accordingly

Comment: I'm also using vagrant. But Ubuntu 14.04. However, this should not being the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the home attribute to the recipe after the user was already created? When I was first hacking around with creating a system user, I didn't add the :manage_home and home bits to the recipe until after I had run the recipe and verified that the user was created. Subsequent runs of the recipe after adding home directory management and the home attribute didn't actually work until I deleted the user and run the recipe again.

I assume that useradd won't execute again if the user already exists, so adding -m  via the recipe wouldn't happen unless and until the user is deleted and the recipe re-runs against a clean system and sends useradd -rm.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this problem and work around it.
The hint was in the chef docs for the [user resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html).
"[homedir] will be created unless CREATE_HOME in /etc/login.defs is set to no". On a fresh Ubuntu install that line did not exist. Perhaps it defaults to no if missing.

In /etc/login.defs I added:

```
CREATE_HOME  yes
```

Once that was added my chef run would complete and create the homedir allowing my to then modify contents of the user homedir. This method may be simpler than manually creating homedirs for each user.

Comment: This is actually problematic. If the user account gets created prior to login.defs being present, the user add will succeed but homedir will not get created.