# Use chef to create user so I can ssh into box

Tags: linux, ssh, chef-infra

We use chef to provision our boxes but most of our deployments are onto windows, as such infrastructure for our linux boxes isn't all there; because of this I can't log on using my own user/password.

The mechanisms for allowing login only work on windows (it's just not a priority for doing it on linux at the moment) and we only have root passwords and I don't have access to that (rightfully so).

However I could create a user during the chef run, I've looked but to be honest they're all kinda confusing, so I thought I'd ask and hope someone with experience might have a better solution.

How do I create a user with admin access so I can ssh in and do what needs to be done on the box via chef?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best guidance I can give:

Use the user resource to create the user and then the sudo cookbook to add this user to the sudoers list.

[User resource documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html)

[A stackoverflow question on the password attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386777/how-do-i-determine-the-password-attribute-value-for-the-chef-user-resource)

[Sudo cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/sudo)

So you should end up with a cookbook containing the following:

metadata.rb

```
[...] # stripped usual lines for cookbook name version
depends 'sudo' # add the dependency to use only one cookbook
```

attributes/default.rb:

```
default['user_to_create'] = "user3536548" # took you SO account here
default['authorization']['sudo']['users'] << node['user_to_create'] # Add the defined user in the array (using attribute to avoid duplication of user name), this avoid overwriting entries from other recipes and as the attribute is initialized as an empty array it will be ok anyway.
```

recipes/default.rb

```
user node['user_to_create'] # create the user, see the doc for details
include_recipe 'sudo' # include the sudo recipe to take advantages of the atrtibutes above.
```

Comment: Can said user ssh in and do admin stuff? Just to clarify, I mean.

Comment: If chef run as root at first, this user will be able to connect (but read the doc to set a password, etc.) and will be added to sudoers, so it will be able to run `sudo any command wanted` which will run a command as root.

Comment: Awesome sauce!, tah very much.

Comment: To anyone that might be reading this wondering about passwords, you can go here for information on that (look at the answer to the question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386777/how-do-i-determine-the-password-attribute-value-for-the-chef-user-resource

Comment: @user3536548 Fair enough, I've edited the answer to include it ;) Cleaning previous comment.

Comment: I found out something, `default['authorization']['sudo']['users'] = node['user_to_create']` needs to be an array so it should be `default['authorization']['sudo']['users'] = [node['user_to_create']]`

Comment: Oh yes, or you may do `default['authorization']['sudo']['users'] << node['user_to_create']` in case you have multiples recipes adding users to the list

Comment: Isn't it required? the template kept erroring that that it couldn't call `.each` on a string, I changed it to an array and it worked.

Comment: It has to be an array, yes. I'll update the answer to enlight it in a better way